# Copy data from text file and paste in browser using selenium

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I want to copy the Contents (HTML, JS, CSS) and paste it into the browser (online editor). I am trying to use Selenium Webdriver with Java to accomplish this task How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should use Java Selenium to copy your contents by send key "Ctrl + C "
Secondly, to paste content into Browser, you should get these editor by Id ( or another attribute, but i suggest to use ID ) and use SendKeys "Ctrl + V" to send the content

To copy

```
IWebDriver firefoxDriver = new FirefoxDriver();
IWebElement textBox = Driver.FindElement(By.Id("IdTextFieldToCopy"));
textBox.SendKeys(Keys.CONTROL, 'c');
```

to Paste

```
IWebDriver firefoxDriver = new FirefoxDriver();
IWebElement IdEditorToPaste = Driver.FindElement(By.Id("IdEditorToPaste"));
IdEditorToPaste.Clear();
IdEditorToPaste.SendKeys(Keys.CONTROL, 'v');
```

Hopy it help you

Comment: Thanks for the response.The contents from the file that I want to copy is located in my local system (for e.g. Desktop). I know selenium cannot copy the file from the Desktop, maybe I have to use Java to this, but I am not sure how would I.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium cannot control Desktop apps.
Using [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/), you can achieve the same.
You can execute AutoIt script from your Java code using below code.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("AutoIt Script Path on your Local System");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use file handling in python to open and read files and do remaining stuff using selenium asusually.

```
list=[]
f1= open("text.txt",r)
for f in f1:
   list.append(f)
## write selenium code as required
```

hope this helps